# New to JsonPath and API Automation. Need suggession on how do i extract value for below JSON with a condition

Tags: java, json, api, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "customerId":"2kXE3upOg5hnOG",
         "ccoId":"paalle",
         "userGroups":[
            "CX Cloud Super Admins",
            "CX Cloud Admins",
            "aAutoGroupMarked12"
         ],
         "emailId":"paalle@test.com",
         "fullName":"Pavan Alle",
         "isSelected":true
      },
      {
         "customerId":"2kXE3upOg5hnOG",
         "ccoId":"rtejanak",
         "userGroups":[
            "aTestUserGroupname1234"
         ],
         "emailId":"rtejanak@test.com",
         "fullName":"Raja Ravi Teja Nakirikanti"
      }
   ],
   "pagination":{
      "pageNumber":1,
      "totalPages":2,
      "rowPerPage":10,
      "totalRows":11
   }
}
```

This is my JSON, where is want to extract ccoId, if and only if the userGroups have a group name as aAutoGroupMarked12. I am new to API automation and JsonPath.
In my company, we were told to use io.rest-assured API's JsonPath class. can someone please give me suggestions on how should I write a path which returns me ccoId value

Answer (score 0):

I would use POJO to filter out the reults based on `userGroups` field.
POJO is a Java class representing JSON. Your JSON can be transformed into:

```
public class UserEntity {
    public String customerId;
    public String ccoId;
    public List<String> userGroups;
    public String emailId;
    public String fullName;
    public Boolean isSelected;
}
```

Each of the variable names need to be exactly like the names in the JSON.

Now, below line transforms JSON into `List<UserEntity>` so we transform JSON to Java classes

```
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from("json String or File");
UserEntity[] userEntities = jsonPath.getObject("$.users", UserEntity[].class);
```

We tell `Rest-Assured's Json Path` to look for `users` element in JSON. It's a list so we transform it into an Array, then we can also change it to list and iterate.

```
List<UserEntity> usersList = List.of(userEntities);
```

It will make it much easier to operate on. I would recommend using Streams but we'll use regular foreach in this case:

```
public void String getCcoId(List<UserEntity> usersList) {
    for (UserEntity user : usersList) {
        List<String> userGroups = user.userGroups;
        for (String userGroup : userGroups) {
            if (userGroup.equals("aAutoGroupMarked12")) {
                return user.ccoId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above looks for particular userGroup and if it matches **first** occurrence it returns `ccoId`

Comment: HI thnaks for your response, but i dont want to use this process because its a one time activity, and creating a class for this is heavy for me. Is there any option similar to contains(from java)? or any other way I can do this? Please help